# Plot 3d surface plot in matlab/freemat

Tags: matlab, freemat

I would like to ask about 3d surface plotting. As I am new to it, I was just trying out. Basically, I have 3 parameters, x, y ,z which I have the values from experimental datas and I would like to plot them out. As such, i tried,

```
x= [6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1]
x =
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1
--> y=[2 3 4 5 6 1 6 8]
y =
 2 3 4 5 6 1 6 8
--> z= [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
z =
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
meshgrid(x,y,z)
surf(x,y,z)
```

The plot window did come out but there was no graph. Is my method wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like you have 3D points for each measurement. Are you looking to plot them in 3D? `plot3` might do what you want, unless I am misunderstanding your task.

Comment: yea,i want to plot them in 3d. i was looking through online resources, does surf and plot3 gives me different things? regardless, do u know why there isn't any plot that appears after what i typed above? Thanks!

Comment: `meshgrid` simply returns the grid for the mesh, it doesn't plot. `surf` should plot  when given the right arguments - did it not give you an error maybe?

Comment: no,it doesn't. after i typed surf(x,y,z), the window that shows the graph pops out but there's no graph. Was wondering if i got soemthing wrong somewhere

Comment: Hm, as far as i can tell, it should give you an error since Z has to be a matrix and you've only defined a vector. Your example only really defines a curve, I'm not sure how you go from that to a surface.

Comment: maybe thats why nothing comes out. Basically,I have 3 parameters from experimental datas and I want to plot them out, like x against y against z. Are u suggesting I should use plot3 instead? Do i so the same thing except changing surf to plot3?

Comment: ok thanks. can i just ask using plot3, it wouldn't be able to give me a surface plot right? Am i able to generate a surface plot with the parameters i have?

Comment: I don't know how you would, but also make sure your data actually defines a surface... right now, it seems like measurements in 3d that don't necessarily live on a reasonable surface.

Comment: i get what u mean now.Maybe my example wasn't good. What if my x and y are coordinates instead? and only z changes. that is (x,y)=(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1)... However my z takes on multiple values. How do i put such data?

Comment: Then you can get a surface, and surf() should work. To get the X and Y coordinates you can use meshgrid, e.g: `[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:3, 1:3);`, and then say for each coordinate you have a value Z, like `Z = rand(3, 3);`. Then `surf(X, Y, Z);` should work.

Comment: yes it works.thanks alot! I would just like to ask, I understand that the function rand assigns random values to Z. How do i insert my own data? do i just type Z=[1 2 4...]？

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to start with `plot3`, as you're just describing a set of points in 3D, rather than points on a mesh or surface. See if that does what you want.

```
x = [6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1];
y = [2 3 4 5 6 1 6 8];
z = [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
plot3(x, y, z, '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would plot a surface :

```
%define the data 
x=[6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1];
y=[2 3 4 5 6 1 6 8 2 3 4 5 6 1 6 8];
z=[3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

%Create 3D surface
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=griddata(x,y,z,X,Y);

%Plot the surface
surface(X,Y,Z);
shading interp %makes it look sexy
%xlim([])
%ylim([])
```

Sometimes I use axis limets to make the plot look nicer (eliminates the unneeded white area's); for this set of data I could use  xlim([6 11]) and ylim([2 6]).